# Finding the next n-power rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Good morning guys,

I am working on some subject of topology and stack in a problem that I don't really know where to search for. 
Giving an integer n (>1), a prime and a rational a/b  such that : ${(a/b)}^n<p$

How could we find another  rational e/f such that 
${(a/b)}^n<{(e/f)}^n<p$

That's all :) simple heh?

Good day

Comment: What is $n$ ? Should the inequality $(a/b)^n < p$ be true for all $n$ ?

Comment: Corrected. n an Integer

Comment: @Zubzub: no, that would trivially mean that $a/b\le1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $q = \frac1p$ and $f(x) = x^n - q$.

If $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n < p$, then $\frac{b}{a} > \sqrt[n]{q}$, the unique positive root of $f(x)$. Apply [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to $f(x)$ with seed $x = \frac{b}{a}$, we obtain another approximation for that root.
$$x ' = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{(n-1)x^n + q}{nx^{n-1}}$$
Apply AM $\ge$ GM to the $n$-tuple $(\underbrace{x^n,\cdots,x^n}_{n-1},q)$, we obtain
$$\frac{(n-1)x^n + q}{n} = {\rm AM} \ge {\rm GM} = \left((x^n)^{n-1}q\right)^{1/n} = x^{n-1}\sqrt[n]{q}$$
Since $x^n \ne q$, the above inequality is strict. From this, we can deduce
$$x' > \sqrt[n]{q}$$
Notice $x^n > q$, we have $$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} > 0\quad\implies\quad x' = x - \frac{f(x)}{f(x)} < x$$
Combine these, we have
$$\sqrt[n]{q} < x' < x
\quad\iff\quad q < x'^n < x^n \quad\implies\quad
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n < \left(\frac{e}{f}\right)^n < p$$

where
$$\frac{e}{f} = \frac{1}{x'} = \frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)x^n + q} = \frac{pn(b/a)^{n-1}}{p(n-1)(b/a)^n + 1} = \frac{pnb^{n-1}a}{p(n-1)b^n + a^n}$$

This particular choice of $\frac{e}{f}$ is one rational that meet the requirement stated in question.

Comment: Thanks Achille, this is what I just found also :) u r Great.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n$-th roots of all terms, and you see that what you're looking for is a rational number $\frac ef$ that lies between $\frac ab$ and $\sqrt[n]p$. Between any two non-equal numbers on the number line, there is a rational number, so there is your $\frac ef$.

Explicitly, the irrationality of $\sqrt[n]p$ makes any formula long and unenlightening, but an algorithm is simple enough. Set $\varepsilon = \sqrt[n]p - \frac ab$, and pick a natural number $f>\frac1\varepsilon$. Now the lowest $e$ such that $\frac ab < \frac ef$ will satisfy $\frac ef<\sqrt[n]p$, since $\frac ef - \frac ab \leq \frac1f<\varepsilon$.

The formula you would get from this algorithm, choosing $f$ to be as small as it can be, is
$$
\frac ef = \cfrac{\left\lfloor\cfrac{a}{b}\left \lceil\frac1{\sqrt[n]p - a/b}\right \rceil\right\rfloor + 1}{\left \lceil\cfrac1{\sqrt[n]p - a/b}\right \rceil}
$$
I might have made some small mistakes in this formula. I can't tell, because it's such a mess. Also note that showing $\frac ab < \frac ef < \sqrt[n]p$ using this formula directly is not something I would recommend attempting.

Comment: I think the question is to find such e and f (at least one in terms of a,b,p). It's not to prove that $\exists$ e and f such that (...).

Comment: @JaideepKhare Is that better?

Comment: Using the n-rooth here is inapropriate I think. As it will only go for an aproximation in reality to have the $\epsilon$, in which case you don't really need to go further as that approximation would be enough. Therefore the problem should be worked without going through the n-rooth

Answer (score 0):

Primality of $p$ plays no role here and the question is about rational approximations of the $n^{th}$ root of an integer.

You can take the decimal expansion of the root to an arbitrary number of decimals (it suffices to take enough decimals for the inequality to hold).

Comment: First, the primality if p give the non existence of the n-rooth. It Can be extended of course to any natural with such property but finding the solution for p prime would be enough. The problem is purely rational so no n-rooth is given for granted.

Comment: Again, the question has nothing to do with primality and you could use the same approach for an exact $n^{th}$ power (using a $.99999\cdots$ development). I don't know what you mean by "no n-rooth is given for granted".

Comment: I mean the problem is to be solved without usage of irrationals.

Comment: @amineMoussaid: finding the decimals of an $n^{th}$ root is a finite process that involves rationals only.

Comment: It's not clear for me how this will solve our problem. Could you give more devlopped proof.  Thks

Comment: @amineMoussaid: there is no need for a proof. It is a very well known fact that any real number can be approximated as closely as you want by a finite decimal development.

Comment: You Can have a look at Achille's answer. more instructive.